# How to return column heads of top 5 lowest averages when there are multiple duplicate average values in excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, array-formulas

I have the following table below in excel and need to retrieve the column headers for the top 5 lowest averages. However some of the columns have the same averages

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |  Column E |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | --------- |
|    2     |     3    |    4     |     3    |     2     |
```

I tried using Index, Match and Small in my formula however it identifies only first instance of the lowest average (in this instance Column A) and doesn't return Column E.

I need the top 5 lowest averages to appear:

```
Column A 
Column E 
Column B
Column D
Column C
```

Comment: Try: `=TAKE(SORT(WRAPCOLS(TOCOL(A1:E2),5),2),,1)`

Comment: Are these excel formulas? I don't see TAKE and WRAPCOLS coming up?

Comment: May i know what is your excel version?

Comment: @Josey1979 `TAKE()`, `WRAPCOLS()` functions are only available on ***Microsoft-365***.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for non MS 365 version too (Excel 2021):

```
=INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:E2),2),SEQUENCE(5),1)
```

Or using `SORTBY` (probably faster than `SORT` for a large dataset):

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(SORTBY(A1:E1,A2:E2)),SEQUENCE(5))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

**Note**: Since we only have 5 columns it selects all of them, but you can check that if you change in the formula `5` by any lower number it returns less rows.

Comment: The `SEQUENCE` call is unnecessary. `INDEX` will return the entire column if you omit the row parameter like so: `=INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:E2),2),,1)`

Comment: @MarkBalhoff True, but it is necessary for this case, since you need just the first `5` rows, not the entire set. For this case is the same, but not for the general case.

Comment: Fair enough. I got caught in everything in question and answer having exactly five items and failed to remember that was a criteria in the wording.